# How can i use each element in one list as an index for another list?

Tags: python-3.6

```
c=[3,4,5,6,7]
d=[0,1,2,3,4]
new_data=[]
for h in d:
    u=c[d]
    new_data.append(u)
print(new_data)
```

My o/p should be = [3,4,5,6,7]

I am a beginner in Python. I don't know if the above code is correct.

Using d as index I need to get the values in c so that I can append values to a new list ie new_data.

Comment: I'm not a python programmer, but shouldn't it be u=c[h] instead of u=c[d]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you assign the values in `d` to `h` while you iterate through `d`, you should use `h` as index to access `c`:

```
c=[3,4,5,6,7]
d=[0,1,2,3,4]
new_data=[]
for h in d:
    u=c[h]
    new_data.append(u)
print(new_data)
```

This outputs:

```
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```